# Using output statistics in ArcGIS REST API query?

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, definition-query, python-3, request

I am using an API to pull in some Web Mapping Service Layer data to my script. The API query has a max count limit of 1000 on returned features per request. There are 2 attributes I am trying to use in my query 1) A `DFIRM_ID` field that has the same value for multiple features (its not unique but there are many `DFIRM_ID` values) and 2) The `OBJECTID` -this is a totally unique value. Each feature has its own `OBJECTID`. My goal is to get the total number of `OBJECTID's` for a given `DFIRM_ID` (or the total number of features). So, I want to use `Output Statistics` in my query. Which also requires 'Group By Fields'. According to the ArcGIS REST API [documentation](https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/sdk/rest/index.html#//02ss0000000r000000), I believe I should have ``. But the outputStatistics part seems confusing (as to how to put it in my query. The documentation says the following syntax (or something like it) is to be used:

```
[{
"statisticType": "<count | sum | min | max | avg | stddev | var>",
"onStatisticField": "DFIRM_ID", 
"outStatisticFieldName": "DFIRM_COUNT"
}]
```

I am just a little confused. How would I use that in my `params` variable below when plugging it into my code?

```
params = {'f': 'json', 'where': 'DFIRM_ID like \'13245%\'+'and OBJECTID>='+str(minCount)+'and OBJECTID<='+str(maxCount), 'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPolygon', 'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects','outFields': '*', 'returnGeometry': 'false'}
r = requests.get('https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/CSLF/Prelim_CSLF/MapServer/3/query', params)
cslfJson = r.json()
master.append(cslfJson)
```

Comment: I think something is missing in *I believe I should have ``*, right?

Comment: Yep. Sorry, it got removed somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statistics you need are the count of `OBJECTID` for each `DFIRM_ID`, so your `onStatisticField` should be `OBJECTID` instead of `DFIRM_ID`. The groupBy parameter should be set to `DFIRM_ID`:

```js
[{
    "statisticType": "count",
    "onStatisticField": "OBJECTID", 
    "outStatisticFieldName": "Count"
}]
```

Which would make your params variable something like this

```py
params = { ....  'groupByFieldsForStatistics': 'DFIRM_ID', 'outStatistics': '[{"statisticType": "count", "onStatisticField": "OBJECTID", "outStatisticFieldName": "Count"}]' }
```

An easy way to find out what the URL should look like is to use the HTML interface of the rest endpoint: https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/CSLF/Prelim_CSLF/MapServer/3/query?f=html

This results in URL (empty parameters removed): https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/CSLF/Prelim_CSLF/MapServer/3/query?where=1%3D1&groupByFieldsForStatistics=DFIRM_ID&outStatistics=%5B%7B%22statisticType%22%3A%22count%22%2C%22onStatisticField%22%3A%22OBJECTID%22%2C%22outStatisticFieldName%22%3A%22COUNT%22%7D%5D&f=html

Here are the first few results:

```
# records: 383

DFIRM_ID: 13245C
COUNT: 8286

DFIRM_ID: 06037C
COUNT: 10632

DFIRM_ID: 17031C
COUNT: 1879

DFIRM_ID: 13115C
COUNT: 2678

DFIRM_ID: 06001C
COUNT: 12788

DFIRM_ID: 04013C
COUNT: 32702

DFIRM_ID: 04025C
COUNT: 2428

DFIRM_ID: 48453C
COUNT: 60419
```

Comment: Do you know how can I sort the results based on count ASC or DESC from server ?

Comment: @MahmoudAdel you could [ask](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new question about that.